# Cannot change com.apple.atrun.plist even with root permissions

Tags: bash, macos, permissions, root, macos-mojave

I'm using OSX Mojave and I've been wanting to use the `at` command to run scripts at certain times, but I've discovered that I need to change its plist file in order to use it. Right now, one of the attributes in it is `Disabled=true` which of course, isn't what I want.

I've gone to the ends of the earth to try to change that. I tried XCode, Pref Setter, chmod, chown, vim, and doing all of that in root. No matter what, it always says, "readonly file" or "You do not have permission."

Are plists supposed to be immutable? I'm pretty sure they aren't. Here is some of the things I've tried.

```
~root# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel ...

~root# atrun=/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
~root# chmod 777 $atrun
chmod: Unable to change file mode on 
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist: Operation not permitted
~root# ls -l $atrun
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  444 Aug 22 23:11 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `com.apple.atrun.plist` from `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`
into your home directory or wherever you want to work on it.

Open `com.apple.atrun.plist` with Xcode and the settings will show up in user readable form.

Change the setting for "Disabled" from `1` to `0` then save and exit Xcode

Copy your changed `com.apple.atrun.plist` file to `/Library/LaunchDaemons`

This can be manually launched to enable  batch.